# objc - UITableView Title too wide.. What are my options?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` where I would like to set the tableView title to a wide label.

I'm trying to do something like:
"Daily Schedule - Long Station Name"

Ideally, this would mean a title and a subTitle. As there isn't a subtitle field, is there anyway to display a wide label?

Please note that I am not asking about `UITableView Section Headers`.

This is about the TableViewController`title.`

Thanks

Comment: `UITableView` does not have a `title` property. Do you perhaps mean the navigation bar title?

Comment: A table view doesn't have a self.title. Do you mean the table view controller's title?

Comment: sorry. `tableViewController` title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to the title displayed by the `UINavigationController`. In that case, you can get away with a custom title view, in which you can have two lines in the text label. Here is an example I'm currently using.

```
// Title label is the view we will assign to the titleView property
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 50)];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.text = @"Daily Schedule - Long Station Name";
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:22];
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8;
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Edit or delete the attributes to get the effects you want with your title.

Comment: Great. thanks a lot. That's exactly what I needed. The comments clarifying that the title is that of the controller rather than the tableView are also keepers. Thanks to all.